# How can I use the same address in a C program that will be the same every time I restart it

Tags: c, memory

What I'm looking for is to be able to get all the same addresses or starting address each time I start the program. for example

address1 = 0x7ffde3397580

address2 = 0x7ffde3397584

then when I restart the program it would be the same address. I wrote a little program and each time I run it it starts at a new address such as

address1 =0x7ffd8f366500

not the same as above.
Also If you can point me to a good book or lesson on memory address manipulation in c language that would be great. Most of what I'm finding has more to do with allocation. Another words each time I run the program I want to clear and allocate the same exact memory, not just the amount of memory.

I wrote several programs with struct, ints , arrays and characters. And they all do the same thing. If with loops they will show the same addresses over and over again since after the assignment they Shouldn't change.

I'm sorry about the way this looks, this editor sucks and will take me a bit to figure it out.

Comment: If your program starts at different memory locations, then your OS has done its job.

Comment: So then I will would need to deal with this in the kernal, Yes?

Comment: Yes, mainly in the loader module

Comment: Cool thanks . I've just started learning OS programming, though it will be awhile to do what I want.

Comment: The obvious question - why do you want/need to do this? Could this be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: What you are seeing is called [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) or ASLR. Depending on your OS and/or compiler you might be able to opt-out or disable it.

Comment: Note that on a modern OS, even with ASLR disabled, you might get the same logical memory address each time, but it won't correspond to the same physical memory address, because a new page will be mapped in.

Comment: Stack Overflow has [multiple questions about how to disable Address Space Layout Randomization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Disable+aslr), which is the likely cause of the variation you are seeing. The method for doing so depends on the operating system you are using. Disabling ASLR should only be done for purposes of debugging and certain other development work. It should not be disabled in deployed applications.

Comment: I'm using Linux, I'm learning how to build Linux, I'm learning Linux OS programming in c. I'm interested in building a network of different devices and as far as security the more tools and control the better the design and security possibilities. I just needed to understand the direction and what I need to learn and all of these answers are helpful and will keep me busy for awhile. Oh and since this needs to be system specific it won't matter as far as being portable, for that matter I don't want it to be portable. I got a ways do go. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are writing an OS kernel or other binary that is running without underlying OS support (as in how programs ran in the 16 and even more-so 8-bit eras) where the program ends up in memory is pretty much entirely up to the OS.

You could build a non-relocatable image and ig there ar no collisions with addresses the OS loader wants to use it will run but there is no guarantee that tomorrow the loader won't want to use the addresses you need.

The usual answer to this problem is to use memory-mapped files and perform offset calculations into the mapped region. The offsets are constant (or at least calculable but stable) while the actual address varies from run to run.

Comment: The variation the OP is seeing is likely caused by Address Space Layout Randomization and can be disabled.